# In a for loop when concatenating strings and numbers why does i-1 need parenthesis but i+1 works

Tags: javascript, math

My question is simple but I couldn't search using the right keywords to find an explanation:

Why does this cause a NaN:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            document.body.innerHTML += 'Number:' + i-1 + '.';
        }
```

But simply changing the minus to a plus doesn't:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            document.body.innerHTML += 'Number:' + i+1 + '.';
        }
```

Snippet for testing:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                document.body.innerHTML += 'Number:' + i-1 + '.';
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+` is both addition and concatenation, and they're left-associative. So the expression

```
'Number:' + i-1 + '.'
```

is parsed as

```
((('Number:' + i)-1) + '.')
```

When you concatenate `'Number:' + i` the result is not a number, so you can't subtract `1` from it. Trying to subtract from something that isn't a number results in `NaN`. You need to use parentheses so that you calculate `i-1` first, then concatenate that to `Number:`.

But when you use `+`, `(('Number:' + i)+1)` means to concatenate `1` to the result of `'Number:' + i`. Since both operations are concatenation you don't get `NaN`.

Note that the `+` version doesn't produce the expected result, since it's not adding. It will print `Number:01.Number:11.Number:21...`, not `Number:1.Number:2.Number:3...`. To get the latter output you need to put `i+1` in parentheses, too.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding an integer to a string here. That results in a behavior where the integer is converted into a string (for example 1->"1") and then that string is appended to the other string (so "Number:"+"1" -> "Number:1").

This kind of behavior, however, is not defined for subtracting. You cannot subtract a string from another string let alone an integer from a string.

That's why you are getting NaN.

When you place the i-1 in parentheses it will first be evaluated as a singular integer (0 if i is 1 etc.) and then this integer is appended to the string using the logic that's described above.

Comment: I'm confused about the part where you cannot subtract an integer from a string, because this seems to work: let myNumber = '5'-3; document.write(myNumber); https://jsfiddle.net/q1pwhsc4/2/

Comment: Barmar gave a nice answer as to why this isn't working that explains this too. If you take a look at it, you'll understand that you are not subtracting 1 from the integer i as a string (like you subtract 3 from '5' in your example, for which there is a defined behavior in javascript) but rather "Number:i" (whatever i is). This is because of the order that it's parsed in as Barmar explains in his answer. If you change the '5' to 'Number:5' in your jsfiddle, you'll get NaN in there too.